# Fabric JS still including default values

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I tried to set the `includeDefaultValues:false` every time I create an object, however, the save string for an image is still:

`[{"type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":396.16,"top":108.16,"width":2475,"height":675,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":0.32,"scaleY":0.32,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"src":"http://localhost/fabricjstest/designs/images/ds130814014834.png?t=1376502517","filters":[]}],"background":"#FFF"}`

I am pretty sure most of those are default values, so how can I get it to work?
Maybe I am saving wrong, so this is my save code:

```
var obj = canvas.toObject();
var jsn = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(jsn);
```

Here is the version directly from the js file: `var fabric=fabric||{version:"1.2.9"};`

So the question is: How do I disable default values.

Comment: I looked into it and noticed that this is a bug. I've opened new issue on github: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/795

Thanks!

Comment: This is [now fixed in v1.2.13](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/5ebd697978a4875037b2dcd449219aaeeab5b8ff)

Comment: Great! will be trying it out as soon as possible.